# Convert getSelect query to Collection

Tags: magento-1.9

I am adding a condition to product listing in magento, Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List

But when I've added the condition using getSelect, its not returning as collection as some of functions are missing like setCurrPage().

Basically I want to join catalog stock table to the product collection. Is there any other way around for this?

**Note:: I am trying to override the file Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List so the collection**

```
$products = parent::_getProductCollection()->getSelect()->joinLeft( array('css'=> 'cataloginventory_stock_status'), 'css.product_id = e.entity_id', array('css.stock_status'));

return $products;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to add following line with your collection.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( array('css'=> cataloginventory_stock_status), 'css.product_id = main_table.entity_id', array('css.stock_status'));
$collection->setPageSize($this->getConfig('qty'))->setCurPage(1);
```

It's working for me.

Happy Codding. :)

Comment: Didn't work for me.I am overriding the file Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List, but once you applied the getSelect then  its not a collection anymore. You won't get any collection properties from that output.I don't know what to do

Comment: can you share your code here?

Comment: hey. can you print $products?? its return data or not?

Comment: try updated answer.

Comment: I don't need to write the collection its already there , I just want to add some condition to collection, if you use getSelect, its not a collection anymore, it won't have any collection features

Comment: you can you  $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'product_url', 'small_image'));    or  $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('name'=>'orig_price','eq'=>'Widget A'),
    array('name'=>'orig_price','eq'=>'Widget B'),           
));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37049/discussion-between-ajay-patel-and-duke).

Comment: Ajay I am in chat

Answer (score 0):

After doing research of 1 day I got the answer.

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( array('css'=> 'cataloginventory_stock_status'), 'css.product_id = e.entity_id', array('css.stock_status'))->where('css.stock_id=3')->where('css.stock_status=1')->group('e.entity_id');
$this->setCollection($collection);
```

So setCollection was making the select statement to collection object again.

```
$this->setCollection($collection);
```

Thanks everyone.